# How to access json value stored in an obervable in knockout

Tags: javascript, html, json, knockout.js, observable

I have a knockout observable "orderDetails" and I am recieving a json response from a rest call which I am then storing in orderdetails. but I am not able to access the value of the json keys. Below is the sample code:

```
self.orderDetails = ko.obervable();
```

after rest call:

```
self.orderDetails({name:"john", b:13, c:14});
```

Now in the html (where "orders" is the viewmodel):

```
<span data-bind="text:$parent.orders.orderdetails.a"></span>
```

This is giving the value as empty. How do I access the name value from the orderDetails.

Comment: This is the [first tutorial lesson](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro) and one of the first chapters in [the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading-and-writing-observables)... Have you spend some doing your own research?

Comment: (The answer is: you call the observable to get its value. `$parent.orders.orderDetails().name`. Note that this will throw an error if `orderDetails()` is `undefined` or `null`.)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0o89pmju/38/

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may be looking for the "With Binding"

The with binding creates a new binding context, so that descendant elements are bound in the context of a specified object.

Here is a very basic example of switching the binding context to a child object. Notice that in the data-bind attributes, it is not necessary to prefix a or b with orderdetails., because the binding context is switched to orderdetails.

```
<p data-bind="with: $parent.orders.orderdetails">
    a: <span data-bind="text: b"> </span>,
    b: <span data-bind="text: c"> </span>
</p>
```

You will need to initialize your orderdetails observable with the child objects using ko.applyBindings. Here is an example.

```
 ko.applyBindings({
    orderdetails: {
        name: "adam",
        b: 13,
        c: 14
    }
});
```

Here is a link with some more info on this: [The "with" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) (The above examples are taken directly from here)

As the comments mention though, you will want to go through all of the tutorials before anything. They are extremely helpful and very informative. [KO tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro)